# Можно ли получить число N при помощи /*-+()?

Tags: java, алгоритм, олимпиада

Условие:

> Даны a, b, c, d, N. (`int`). Следует определить, возможно ли получить `N`
>   при помощи `/*-+()`, используя каждое число только **1** раз?

Один из возможный примеров:

> Пример: [1,5,7,8], N = 24.
>    Ответ: TRUE. ( 1 + 7 ) * ( 8 - 5 ) = 24.

Что попытался сделать я?

- Использовать польскую запись. Генерировать все возможные значения, типа `abcd*-/`. Данный способ не работает, т.к. пример выше опровергает. (не получается сгенерировать всевозможные комбинации).

Дальше пытался так:

```
if (Item1.equals("+")) {
            if (Item2.equals("+")) {
                if (Item3.equals("+")) {
                    Ans = Number1 + Number2 + Number3 + Number4;
                }
            }
        }
```

Но таким образом, такую операцию надо делать 27 раз без учета скобок.

Кто может предложить оптимальное решение?

Comment: *не получается сгенерировать всевозможные комбинации* Почему? всего-то два варианта - ABxCDyz и ABxCyDz. ABCD - цифры (24 варианта), xyz - операции (64 варианта). Всего вычислить надо максимум 24*64=1536 вариантов (отбрасывать дубликаты из-за перестановок сложнее, чем просчитать все). Если какой подойдёт - разворачиваешь его в выражение, а нет - значит нет.

Comment: а как получить эти варианты не руками?

Comment: @Kromster там просто число получить, а мне бы алгоритм)

Comment: Так там алгоритмы в ответах приведены. Помотрите первый ответ хотя бы - *"Вкратце, для всевозможных перестановок данных чисел пытаемся всеми возможными способами расставить скобки и действия между ними."*

Comment: там надо найти всевозможные варианты, а мне только одного хватит. но числа-то могут меняться

Comment: Зачем руками-то? программно это всё делается. Генеришь перестановку чисел, генеришь сочетание операций, подставляешь всё это в каждый вариант и считаешь. 2 вложеных цикла.

Comment: Упс. Пропустил ещё варианты ABCxyDz и ABCxDyz.